# Can a m3u8 file contain other m3u8 files?

Tags: http, m3u8

I want to stream to `IPAD` by `Apple HTTP Streaming Tech`. Is it possible to embed other `M3U8` files like the include command in the c program?

For example main.m3u8:

```
includes 
1.m3u8
2.m3u8
```

So that `IPAD` can play *1.m3u8*, then *2.m3u8* and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As I know you can use `EXT-X-STREAM-INF`tag to include file.
The document is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/HTTPLiveStreaming/index.html)
May be you can use `PROGRAM-ID`to sign different media file
but, I haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it may work like this.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=744100,RESOLUTION=640x480
chunklist_w136620713_b744100_sleng.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1044100,RESOLUTION=854x480
chunklist_w136620713_b1044100_sleng.m3u8
```

You can include more resolution to include multiple m3u8.